# Show how to obtain decision tree will classify the test instance <sunny,mild,normal,weak>?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees

Given the question,
[image]

---

The decision tree for this is,

[image]

But unable to predict the sample. Can anyone help me in this question. TIA

Comment: It's a decision tree, it's very simple. The top node means "if the outlook is sunny then go left node, otherwise if the outlook is rainy then go right node". Then you do it gain until you reach a leaf at the bottom, telling you the answer.

Comment: Have you checked the question? After reaching to node Humidity through sunny i got sunny and normal. From where I could match the sample ?

Comment: It's not clear what is your difficulty: with humidity==normal you reach the 2nd leaf and this leaf is labelled 'yes', so the prediction for this instance is 'yes'.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to match all features. If outlook is Sunny and humidity is normal the answer will be yes irrespective what is the value for wind, temperature .
In other words , if the outlook is Sunny it is enough for the model to know humidity to decide the outcome